# Regex to extract where clause parameterized columns

Tags: regex

How can I extract parameterized columns using regex from sql string below:

```
select * from table1 
where column1 = ?1 
and column2 = 'a' 
and column3 like ?2 or column3 > ?3
```

From the above sql regex capture group should return:

```
column1 = ?1
column3 like ?2
column3 > ?3
```

I don't want to use any full fledged sql parser. All I need is the names of columns that are being compared (`<`, `>`, `=`, `like`, `not like`, `!=`) to parameters `?1`, `>2`, etc.

Comment: What language/tool are you using for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is suggestion:

```
(\w+)\s+(?:(not\s+)?like|=|>|<)\s+\?\d+
```

**Explanation:**

- `(\w+)\s+` any alphanumeric characters followed by spaces
- `(?:(not\s+)?like|!?=|>|<)\s+` accepted operators followed by spaces
- `\?\d+` parameterized column (a `?` followed by digits)

This first group of this regex extracts the column names from your input:

```
column1
column3
column3
```

The full group extracts the whole condition:

```
column1 = ?1 
column3 like ?2
column3 > ?3
```

#### [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QkJH5l/1)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no reason to believe you have multiple spaces between substrings and because you say you are looking for parameters that start with `?` or `>`, this is a pattern optimized for accuracey, efficiency, and brevity:

```
\w+ (?:[<=>]|!=|(?:not )?like) [?>]\d+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WkRsh5/1)